# Make image responsive with specific height of parent container

Tags: html, css

I want to make image responsive fit with container without stretching the image. Is there any way to make it?

```css
.img-wrapper {
  height: 50vh;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Responsiveness</h1>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src=https://levels.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/coworking-space.jpg>
</div>
```

it is very similar with jumbotron and using image tag because fetching url from backend, I already try to use max-width:100% and max-height:100% also height:auto but doesn't work. What I want is make image fit within container width and height, without any stretch or at least minimize the stretch on image

Thanks :)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jovimassimiliano/pen/zwaoPz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for Support IE too**

for your img tag :

```
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
```

try this:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper > img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .img-wrapper > img {
       min-width:650px;
       top: 0;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Responsiveness</h1>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src=https://levels.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/coworking-space.jpg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Take `img` atribute out of `img-wrapper` class
2. add `overflow: hidden` to `img-wrapper`
3. change `height` to `auto`

```css
.img-wrapper{
 height:50vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
img{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Responsiveness</h1>

<div class="img-wrapper">
 <img src=https://levels.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/coworking-space.jpg>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i want to make width 100%. It's same as jumbotron class on bootstrap but with specific height. so I need to make image width 100% and fit with height of container without any stretch or maybe minimum stretch on image

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use image tag you can put the graphic as a background of the div and use CSS

```
div {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Instead of "contain" you can play with the other options as well. Usually the effect you desire can be achieved with combinations like:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: auto 100%;
background-size: cover;
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Mchaov/pen/NjzpWy

further reading on w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp